What is the Biblical basis that Jesus Christ is Jehovah God's first direct creation, even before Adam?
The Jehovah's Witnesses teach the Son of God was the first and direct creation of Jehovah God:

Jesus Christ is shown to be “the firstborn of all creation” as well as “the firstborn from the dead”​—not merely most distinguished in relation to those created or those resurrected but the first one actually created and the first raised from the dead to endless life. (Col 1:15, 18; Re 1:5; 3:14) (Firstborn, Firstling, jw.org)

The Bible says at Genesis 1:26 that Adam was the first man created by God. There are approximately 4,000 years from Adam to Jesus Christ be born. There are about 60 years from Jesus' resurrection to when the Apostle Paul wrote Colossians 1:15, "And He is the image of the invisible God, the first-born of all creation."
So here's my question: What is the Biblical basis for the teaching that Jesus Christ is Jehovah God's first direct creation, even before Adam?

While we have had several questions asking how this first creation doctrine can be reconciled with various passages, I think this is the first time that the Biblical basis for the teaching has been directly asked.

@MrBond I couldn't find what you meant by "The Kingdom is at Hand", but if you can give a more specific reference/quote (ideally a website) you should add it back in.

"What is the Biblical basis that Jesus Christ is Jehovah God's first direct creation" sounds a bit of an unnecessary question to ask, being that a  "Biblical basis" answer is in the Bible verses at the end of the quoted text: Colossians 1:15 (Jesus is referred to as "firstborn of all creation") and Revelation 3:14 (Jesus refers to himself as " the beginning of the creation of God").

@alec Revelation 3:14, In the Greek the word for Beginning is "arche." Strong's #G746. beginning, origin, the person or thing that commences, that by which anything begins to be." We get our English word "architect" from the Greek word, "arche" What do you think the job of an architect is? Also notice, "the Beginning "OF" the creation of God. It does not say the "Beginning" "BY" the creation of God. How can Jesus be created in view of John 1:3 and Colossians 1:16? "Firstborn of all creation" speaks of Christ's preexistence, sovereignty, and redemption, not first created. Jesus is the creator!

In reply to your reply: I'll let JWs answer questions to their religion but was just pointing out that they were already referencing scriptures in that text you quoted. Other than that, claiming something about Jesus natuire because of the etymology and nature of the term "architect" is just nonsense. And the fact that something was created through Jesus is probably not so different from when people were healed through him. Since he was a man (while on earth), it must have been God's spirit that flowed through him and accomplished miracles.

Every individual, organisation or piece of literature that claims Jesus Christ is Jehovah God's first direct creation depends on several things.
First, that when the Bible says that in the beginning was the Word of God (who became flesh as the man, Jesus Christ), that he was with God "in the beginning", and that he was God: that that is not what the Bible says. After those first 2 verses of the first chapter of John's gospel are denied, they also have to deny verse 3, that "all things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made." Logically, if the Word made ALL things, he could not have been made himself. Had the Word been created by Jehovah God as the first creature God created, John would have had to say, "All things (apart from himself) were made by him."
As the Bible does not say that, some groups produce their own translations that  deny that by changing the wording to accommodate their doctrine. This includes insisting that some Greek words (that can be translated as literally 'first-born' must mean that Jesus was first-created), or that 'only begotten Son' must be interpreted as born (i.e., having a starting point in time.)
The second means employed is interpretation of texts that actually don't mention Jesus, such as Proverbs chapter 8, to say it means that  "wisdom" was the first thing Jehovah produced (i.e., created), and that this is an allusion to the Word (who became the man Jesus Christ). Thus, they say, the Word is Wisdom, and was produced - not eternal, in other words.
Third, they insist that to understand the correct interpretation of scripture about Jesus Christ, it is necessary to go to their leaders for instruction, as only their group (and leadership) is approved of God. This goes along with the claim that every denomination that believes Christ (the Word) to be the uncreated Creator is an agent of Satan, and must be got out of, if God's adverse judgment is not to be experienced by them.
That is it in a nutshell. The question does not require an argument to develop about an answer such as this, for this is just stating how the Bible is viewed, and used, by many who deny Christ to be the uncreated Creator. Neither is this answer picking out any one denomination as using those three bases, either. The three points are readily seen to be employed by a range of denominations, whilst it remains true that this certainly applies to the denomination tag for the question.

+1. Many thanks, Anne - an excellent summary.

I can think of a couple verses that lend support to the idea that the Son was created before all else (and through which all else was made).
The first would be Proverbs 8. It was common in the early church (prior to the Trinity doctrine) to identify Christ as the wisdom of God in Proverbs 8.
Proverbs 8:22-31 (Wisdom speaking)

22 “The Lord created me at the beginning of His way, Before His works of old. 23 From eternity I was established, From the beginning, from the earliest times of the earth. 24 When there were no ocean depths, I was born, When there were no springs abounding with water. 25 Before the mountains were settled, Before the hills, I was born; 26 While He had not yet made the earth and the fields, Nor the first dust of the world. 27 When He established the heavens, I was there; When He inscribed a circle on the face of the deep, 28 When He made firm the skies above, When the springs of the deep became fixed, 29 When He set a boundary for the sea So that the water would not violate His command, When He marked out the foundations of the earth; 30 Then I was beside Him, as a master workman;And I was His delight daily, Rejoicing always before Him, 31 Rejoicing in the world, His earth, And having my delight in the sons of mankind.

This identification can first of all be supported directly by Paul, who says that Jesus is the wisdom of God:
1 Corinthians 1:24

... Christ the power of God and the wisdom of God.

The second - and complementary - way to support this is through Christ's identity as the light of mankind (John 1:4; John 8:12). For the first act of creation was the light (Genesis 1:3-5). But note: this light is not the light of the sun nor of the moon nor the stars, which came later.
The second act of creation was to separate the waters above and below by an expanse. The expanse God called heaven.
Note that in Proverbs 8, wisdom speaks of being there when the heavens were established (the second act of creation), but it does not state that wisdom was present prior to the creation of the light.
I'm partial to this interpretation myself - as opposed to the Trinity. And I haven't seen any good arguments directly against it either as of yet.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

So, prior to God creating His Wisdom He had none?

@MikeBorden Does Tertullian answer your question here? The acquiring of Wisdom was not that God at some point was without wisdom and then acquired it (How could God be without his wisdom and be God?); rather, it was “in fact the beginning of his ways: this meditation and arrangement being the primal operation of Wisdom, opening as it does the way to the works by the act of meditation and thought.”[12] God’s creating was done in (by) Wisdom.

@MikeBorden Any answer is going to be somewhat speculative - but personally, I think by wisdom what is more specifically meant is God's design/plan for creation and for us. He didn't just start creating willy-nilly - he first sat down and thought through how, if and when we sinned, he would go about bringing us back to himself. And that is accomplished, of course, through Christ.

@Aleph-Gimel That is my understanding as well.  God did not create his wisdom but in creation it was manifested. This does not lead to the conclusion that Jesus Christ, as the wisdom of God, was created. God meditated and planned in his rational mind. That rational mind is the Logos, which was made flesh.  Manifested and not created.

That thinking and planning is the Logos, which is not just the word spoken but the rational mind behind the word.  The wisdom of Proverbs 8 is the Logos of John 1.  God's rational mind manifested generally in creation and personally in flesh.

@MikeBorden agreed

Insight on the Scriptures, Volume 1 p. 527 says:

Jehovah’s first creation was his “only-begotten Son” (John 3:16), “the
beginning of the creation by God.” (Revelation 3:14) This one, “the firstborn
of all creation,” was used by Jehovah in creating all other things,
those in the heavens and those upon the earth, “the things visible and
the things invisible.” (Colossians 1:15-17) John’s inspired testimony
concerning this Son, the Word, is that “all things came into existence
through him, and apart from him not even one thing came into
existence,” and the apostle identifies the Word as Jesus Christ, who
had become flesh. (John 1:1-4, 10, 14, 17) As wisdom personified, this
One is represented as saying, “Jehovah himself produced me as the
beginning of his way,” and he tells of his association with God the
Creator as Jehovah’s “master worker.” (Proverbs 8:12, 22-31) In view of the
close association of Jehovah and his only-begotten Son in creative
activity and because that Son is “the image of the invisible God” (Colossians
1:15; 2 Corinthians 4:4), it was evidently to His only-begotten Son and master
worker that Jehovah spoke in saying, “Let us make man in our
image.”​ — Genesis 1:26.

Jehovah‘s Witnesses believe that Jesus as the Word (John 1:1-3) or Wisdom (Proverbs 8) was only begotten (John 1:18) or brought forth/born (Proverbs 8:22).
As for the timing, when this happened, note that it was the very first act of God in connection with creation - Proverbs 8 talking about "the beginning of His [God's] ways".
Insight on the Scriptures, Volume 1 p. 527 goes on to say:

After creating his only-begotten Son, Jehovah used him in bringing the
heavenly angels into existence. This preceded the founding of the
earth, as Jehovah revealed when questioning Job and asking him: “Where
did you happen to be when I founded the earth . . . when the morning
stars joyfully cried out together, and all the sons of God began
shouting in applause?” (Job 38:4-7) It was after the creation of these
heavenly spirit creatures that the material heavens and earth and all
elements were made, or brought into existence. And, since Jehovah is
the one primarily responsible for all this creative work, it is
ascribed to him.​— Nehemiah 9:6; Psalm 136:1, 5-9.
The Scriptures, in stating, “In the beginning God created the heavens
and the earth” (Genesis 1:1), leave matters indefinite as to time. This use
of the term “beginning” is therefore unassailable, regardless of the
age scientists may seek to attach to the earthly globe and to the
various planets and other heavenly bodies. The actual time of creation
of the material heavens and earth may have been billions of years ago.

Logical thinking implies that when Jesus is the literal "firstborn of all creation" (Colossians 1:15) and the "beginning of God's creations" (Revelation 3:14), EVERYTHING (excluding the pre-human Jesus) was created AFTER him. As stated in the 'Insight on the Scriptures' book quoted above, this may have been "billions of years ago" - even before any material creation. The pre-human Jesus existed BEFORE every other person ever created by God.
Jesus is not once called creator/co-creator in the Bible. In Matthew 19:4, Jesus says: "Have you not read that the One having created from the beginning 'made them male and female'", thus attributing the creation to someone else than himself.
John 1:3, 10, Colossians 1:16, 17, Hebrews 1:2, 10 may look like they attribute creation to Jesus, but a closer look at the koine Greek text reveals that Jesus was God's instrument through whom He created everything (Greek: dia short form di') - Not once is the Greek word hupo (English: by) used in connection with Jesus' role in creation - he is thus never mentioned as the source of creation. (Compare Matthew 1:22 to see the use of 'dia' and 'hupo' in a single verse - 'dia' denoting agency/intrumentality).
Colossians 1:16 also says that creation happened "in" Jesus (Greek: 'en'), NAS Exhaustive Concordance describing the word origin as:

a prim. preposition denoting position and by impl. instrumentality

While bringing into existence of the pre-human Jesus could be called a creative act by God Almighty, it differs from all (other) creation, in that everything else was created by GOD through the Word/Wisdom/Jesus as God‘s „master workman“ (Proverbs 8:30; Colossians 1:15,16).
If you compare the Interlinear of Proverbs 8:22 with Genesis 4:1, you also will find that Eve used the same verb to describe her giving birth to Cain than is used in Proverbs to describe the bringing about of "Wisdom" (Hebrew: קָנָה, transliterated: qanah, which means "to acquire" - Strong's 7069). Many bible translations thus translate Proverbs 8:22 by saying that the Wisdom was "brought forth"(NIV), "formed"(NLT), "created"(NASB), "made"(ISV) by the LORD YHWH, "at the beginning of His work".
How is the Wisdom of God in Proverbs 8 connected to Jesus?
Jesus is described numerous times in the bible to be "the Wisdom of God" - Paul describes it in 1 Corinthians 1:24 calling "Christ the power of God and the wisdom of God", and in Colossians 2:3 talking about Christ "in whom are hidden all the treasures of wisdom and knowledge". Jesus calls himself the wisdom of God in Luke 11:49.
Furthermore, God's attributes are eternal - hence God's internal wisdom cannot be the subject in Proverbs 8, as he does neither have to "acquire" it (or "bring it forth"), and being eternal God's internal wisdom doesn't have a "beginning". The personified wisdom in Proverbs 8 was brought forth at the beginning of God's ways though, hence it is someone who has a beginning. As shown through the verses in the paragraph above, it is pretty clear from the Bible that this personified wisdom that God "brought forth" at the "beginning of his ways" is Jesus!
Hence Proverbs 8 is one OT reference that they would mention and derived from that Job 38:4-7 to show that Jesus was brought into existence before any other type of person.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The first basis is the gospel of Saint John, Saint John refers to Jesus as The true light, which gives light to everyone, was coming into the world.
John 1:9

The true light, which gives light to everyone, was coming into the world. He was in the world, and the world was made through him, yet the world did not know him.

Now Saint John uses the article The to refer to that light, Saint John has personified it meaning that this light is an entity
now I want you to back track to Genesis where the light is introduced, this light in Genesis is the same light that Saint John was talking about.
Genesis 1:3

And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. And God saw that the light was good. And God separated the light from the darkness. God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night

God called the light Day, did you hear that, he called Jesus Day and where else in scripture do we find Jesus being referred to as the Ancient of Days whose hair was as white as wool.
Daniel 7:9

As I looked, thrones were placed, and the Ancient of Days took his seat; his clothing was white as snow, and the hair of his head like pure wool; his throne was fiery flames; its wheels were burning fire.

Scripture explains itself, Jesus Christ was the beginning of God's creation as it is also mentioned in Revelation, the great light that God called out darkness
Revelation 3:14

And to the angel of the church in Laodicea write: ‘The words of the Amen, the faithful and true witness, the beginning of God's creation.

He is called the beginning of God's creative works because of the verse in Genesis.

Good insights :)

You have posted this answer before! I want to address Revelation 3:14 and show you from the Greek that Jesus Christ is "NOT" a created being. In the Greek the word for "Beginning" is "arche." Strong's #G746. "beginning, origin, the person or thing that commences, that by which anything begins to be." We get our English word "architect" from the Greek word, "arche" What do you think the job of an architect is? Also notice, "the Beginning  "OF" the creation of God. It does not say the "Beginning" "BY" the creation of God. How can Jesus be created in view of John 1:3 and Colossians 1:16?

@Mr.Bond. you have to understand that this light was not the sun, the sun was created on the fourth day, this light was spiritual and supernatural. The language used here is very symbolic, you have to read in between the lines

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Why read in between the lines when I can read what it actually says. Genesis 1:1, "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. At vs14 God does not
just say, Let there be lights, and that's the end of it. He says Let there be lights in the expanse of the heavens to separate the day from the night. In other words, God's command at Genesis 1:1 assumes the lights were already in the expanse and  that in response to His command they were given a purpose, to separate day from the night to mark seasons and days and years. (Commentary by Frank E. Gaebelein)

@Mr.Bond, I am telling you Jesus is the light or the day and the serpent is the night or the darkness, you need an inspiration of the holy spirit to understand these things, God indirectly created darkness when he called out the light
